# MySQL - Find the latest version of the First Child

Tags: mysql, row-number, mysql-5.7

I have a Parent object that has many Versions.

```
CREATE TABLE version (
    id int,
    item_id int,
    logged_at datetime,
    parent_id int
);

CREATE TABLE parent (
  id int
);

INSERT INTO version (id, item_id, logged_at, parent_id)
VALUES (1, 1, "2021-12-01 20:00:00", 1);
INSERT INTO version (id, item_id, logged_at, parent_id)
VALUES (2, 1, "2021-12-01 20:20:00", 1);
INSERT INTO version (id, item_id, logged_at, parent_id)
VALUES (3, 1, "2021-12-01 21:40:00", 1);
INSERT INTO version (id, item_id, logged_at, parent_id)
VALUES (4, 2, "2021-12-01 21:40:00", 1);
INSERT INTO version (id, item_id, logged_at, parent_id)
VALUES (5, 2, "2021-12-01 20:20:00", 1);

INSERT INTO parent (id)
VALUES (1);
```

As you can see, each `Version` belongs to different `Items`. Where the only thing differentiating them is the `.item_id` they belong to and the `.logged_at` attribute.

My objective is to find the **lowest** `.item_id` Version with the **latest** `.logged_at`.

Thus the desired result should in this example be :

```
VALUES (3, 1, "2021-12-01 21:40:00", 1);
```

I understand row_number() partitions can acquire the first child, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to do a secondary faceted search.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it like this.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY logged_at DESC) row_num
FROM VERSION
ORDER BY logged_at DESC, row_num, item_id
LIMIT 1
```

Sort by `item_id` according to `logged_in` time by `PARTITION BY` syntax.

Then, for items with the same `item_id`, the ranking is determined according to the `logged_in`.

From that table, `order by logged_in desc` is the primary to know the most recently logged in user, and `order by row_num, item_id` are secondary to select the lowest `item_id` among users who logged in at the same time.

Comment: That's awesome Silverstar. Thank you so much. Wishing you a great weekend.